# FSO OpenTextFile with french characters

Tags: asp-classic, character-encoding, fso

Using ASP's file system object (FSO), I'm trying to read a txt file with `OpenTextFile` that contains French characters (e and a with accents for e.g). Those characters come out wrong.

I tried specifying the [format](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_opentextfile.asp) to `TristateTrue` to open the file as Unicode but to no avail.

I've been reading about using the ADO Stream object instead but I hoped there would be a way with FSO. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "Those characters come out wrong."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the file is saved in UTF-8 encoding.  The FileSystemObject does not handle UTF-8.

Either have the file saved as Unicode or use the `ADODB.Stream` object.  The `ADODB.Stream` has a `LoadFromFile` method and does support UTF-8.

```
 Dim s

 Dim stream : Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

 stream.CharSet = "UTF-8"
 stream.LoadFromFile Server.MapPath("yourfile.txt")

 s = stream.ReadAll

 stream.Close
```

Comment: It should be noted this will only work if the stream is opened first with `stream.Open`. Also, maybe something with the API has changed since this answer was written, but the I think the correct method is `stream.ReadText`.